# Can't determine input shape and type of Convolutional Layer in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm following [this](https://github.com/jrieke/shape-detection/blob/master/single-rectangle.ipynb) github repository for implementing simple object detection. In that repository, no convolution layers are used, but I want to add two convolution layers before Dense layer. So I've changed the code of `model` as following:

```
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2), input_shape=(1, 16, 16), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

And also I've changed the dimensions of images from `8*8` to `16*16`.

So here my dimension of the input data set will be (40000* 16 * 16), Where 40000 is number of images.

Now I can not decide whether to use `conv1D` or `conv2D`. I've read [this](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) keras official docs, but can't understand much about relationship between dimension of conv. layer and input data shape.

If I use above model configuration, then I'm getting following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected conv2d_21_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (40000, 16, 16)
```

So what I'm missing here? And in general how to decide whether to use `conv1D` or `conv2D`? Thanks for help I'm complete newbie in this field.

Comment: You are missing the `channels` dimension of your tensor. So to say, if you have a greyscale image, probably `channels=1`, RGB: 3, etc. anyhow..your convolutional layer expects a 4D tensor input, while you only supply the first 3, `batch_size, width, height`. To decide on whether to use `conv1D` or `conv2D`: How do you wish to convolute your network? Along 1 dimension, or with a 2D filter?

Comment: but what if I don't have RGB channel?

Comment: Then whatever amount of channels you do have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to shape your images properly. All convolutional layers expect an additional dimension for `channels`.

RGB images have 3 channels. But if you don't have channels, actually you have 1 channel then. You must make this appear in your data for it to work:

```
#if using channels_last - the default configuration in keras
x_train = x_train.reshape(40000,16,16,1)

#if using channels_first
x_train = x_train.reshape(40000,1, 16,16)
```

Notice that the `input_shape` parameter must match exactly the shape of the data, excluding the batch size (40000).

#### Details

For images, you're certainly going to use 2D convolutions (unless you've got some fancy non standard ideas). The 1D convolutions are good for sequences. It's pretty simple:

- 1D convolutions: time series, sequences, audio signals, etc. The data has "length" only.
- 2D all kinds of data in an area. Images are classical cases. They have height and width.
- 3D all kinds of volumetric data. 3D images, for instance. Height, width and depth.

All of them will have `channels`, though, adding an extra dimension to the input.

The 2D convolutional layers expect two possibilities, depending on your keras configuration:

- Channels last (default): `(BatchSize, pixelsX, pixelsY, channels)`
- Channels first: `(BatchSize, channels, pixelsX, pixelsY)`

You don't pass the batch size to `input_shape`, so you may use one of these:

```
#channels last (if you have 1 channel only, but if you have RGB, use 3 instead of 1   
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2), input_shape=(16, 16, 1), activation='relu'))

#channels first (if you have 1 channel only, but if you have RGB, use 3 instead of 1   
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2), input_shape=(1,16, 16), activation='relu'))
```

You can find your keras default configuration in the file located in `<yourUserFolder>/.keras/keras.json`.

You can also pass an individual `data_format` parameter to each convolutional layer if you need.

Comment: `Conv2D` in `keras` also exposes the parameter `data_format` which allows you to specify the ordering of the input shape dimensions if you don't want to manually rearrange them. ( https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/ )

Comment: Yep, it's in the answer :)

Comment: Ohh oops, must've just skipped over that last line!

Comment: Great detailing! Let me try these things and I'll accept the answer! +1 for explanation.